# Workspace mappings with GET params in URL

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How do I map a resource with GET params in the URL to a local resource in a workspace folder?

For example, how can I map:

```
C:/some/local/path/to/script.js
```

to:

```
http://localhost/remote/path/to/script.js?version=1&something=2
```

It looks like dev tools only supports mapping a url prefix.

Comment: Feel free to star https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=277885

Comment: Thanks!  Just starred it.